# Angular-formly with Font awesome

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, angular-formly

I want to know if it is possible to use an Font Awesome icon with Angular-formly.
I am using Angular-formly with bootstrap and now i wat to add Font Awesome icon to the right of the field. 
This is how my Angular-formly is setup

```
            field = {
                className: 'col-md-3',
                key: name,
                type: typeObject.type,
                templateOptions: {
                    "valueProp": "name",
                    disabled: typeObject.disabled,
                    type: 'text',
                    label: name,
                    required: true,
                    options: typeObject.options,
                    fieldData: value,
                    addonRight: {text:"Font Awesome icon here"}
                }
            };
```

So is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible and there's already [an example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/input-add-ons) for it. Just replace the bootstrap classes with font awesome classes and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to add it to the label?

Comment: You'll have to write your own wrapper. Here's the bootstrap one: https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap/blob/master/src/wrappers/label.html